# wpf datagrid alternate row coloring

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, styles, wpfdatagrid

I have tried this method..   without luck..

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
  <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
     </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is there a way to get the row Index?
I have even tried

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AlternationIndex}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Unless already done, you have to set the AlternationCount property of DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid AlternationCount="2"
          ... />
```

You should additionally check whether the Foreground property is used for any Control in the DataGridRow. Try setting the Background property to test the alternation stuff.

Comment: I was searching around and came across this and was like "Aah yes!".  :)   Thanks though!..

Comment: 12 years later this is now changed. Setting the `AlternatingRowBackground` property automatically sets the `AlternationCount` property to 2.

Answer (score 54):

Finally, this is what I ended up with for generically setting alternate row colors.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF" />
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
</Style>

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCC"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEE"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this I use, because I want the alternation colour override with my own when condition met:

Comment: There is a built in property for this purpose: "AlternatingRowBackground", you can set the "Background" to one color and the  "AlternatingRowBackground" to a second color,  no need for this trigger.

Answer (score 35):

Try setting the alternating background like this:

```
  AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="Bisque"
```

Comment: This is the best solution I have come across, because it is short to the point.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
  <DataGrid AlternationCount="2"
            AlternatingRowBackground="Salmon" ........
```

Comment: This answer was already suggested by [@Th3G33k](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35301853/1708751).

Answer (score 3):

Finally I used combination of Robin Maben and Th3G33k solution, because I want the alternation colour to override with my own, when some condition is met.
Thanks both.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridCustomerOrderItems" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  AlternationCount="2"
                  IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <!--first alteraniting colour-->
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEE"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <!--then override with my own colour-->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InvoiceSet}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks for stretching the answer. This is also what I'm looking for.