# Different color for different items in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, wpf-controls

How can I define different colors in each row of ListView automatically? for example if I have such classes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Fruit> _fruits = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>();
    public ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruits { get { return _fruits; } }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Fruits.Add(new Fruit { Name = "apple", Count = 3 });
        Fruits.Add(new Fruit { Name = "orange", Count = 10 });
        Fruits.Add(new Fruit { Name = "apple", Count = 3 });
        Fruits.Add(new Fruit { Name = "banana", Count = 8 });

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

And this is a XALM:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Fruit" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Count" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Count}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

How can I make all rows with apples to be red, oranges yellow e.t.c. without edit Fruit class?

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question. Actually, there are two types of color highlighting available in WPF. 

The first type allows you to use a different color for each item.
The second one alloww you to setup interlaced labeling of your rows. 

So my question is which one is suitable for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare following Style in View.xaml resources, it will be applied to the each ListView Item. Considering that into the each ListViewItem.DataContext is set object of type `Fruit` you ca set DataTrigger on `Name` property:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem"> 
    <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="apple">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
         </DataTrigger>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="orange">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="orange" />
         </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that.

The first way is to use DataTemplates which allows you to select color by state of your object. You can read about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

Also, you can always specify alternation count of rows. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792628/wpf-datagrid-alternate-row-coloring)