# WPF DataGrid with Bands

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How do you create a data grid in WPF with multiple bands?

I have been Googling & checking forums, but I can't find a single example

Comment: I don't think the vanilla WPF DataGrid supports that.

Comment: what do you mean by 'bands'?

Comment: @Andrew something like [this](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/xpf/GridBandedViewPict001.jpg)

Comment: My best guess would be to use RowDetails - but that's going to be a world of hurt.

Comment: @HighCore, OP might be just referring to different coloring of even/odd rows

Comment: @NewDev right. I didn't think of that. I guess we will have to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to alternating coloring of rows, check out [`AlternationIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex.aspx) Property. If you set `AlternationCount = 2` you get different even/odd rows. Correspondingly, if you set it to N, then you get N different rows. You can then style rows depending on the `AlternationIndex` count.

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792628/wpf-datagrid-alternate-row-coloring) of how to use AlternationIndex.

Comment: For `DataGrid`s, you can actually skip the style triggers and just set the [AlternatingRowBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.alternatingrowbackground.aspx) property. Of course, this only works for an `AlternationCount` of 2.